# Add Class to Menu Item When Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the menu items to look like they are selected when you are scrolling through certain sections of a single page website

I tried capturing the position of each element and store it in a variable and then apply a class when the top of that element passes the top of the page.

Java Script:

```
 var blockone = Math.abs($("#one").position().top);
 var blocktwo = Math.abs($("#two").position().top);
 var blockthr = Math.abs($("#thr").position().top);
 var blockfou = Math.abs($("#fou").position().top);
 var blockfiv = Math.abs($("#fiv").position().top);
 var blocksix = Math.abs($("#six").position().top);

    function removeSelected() {
        $('#menu li').removeClass('selected');
    }

$("#frame").scroll( function() {   
    $("#menu li:nth-child(1)").addClass('selected');

    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value < blocktwo ){
        removeSelected();
        $("#menu li:nth-child(1)").addClass('selected');  
    } else if (value < blockthr){
        removeSelected();
        $("#menu li:nth-child(2)").addClass('selected');
    }  else if (value < blockfou){
         removeSelected();
         $("#menu li:nth-child(3)").addClass('selected');   

    } else if (value < blockfiv){
         removeSelected();
         $("#menu li:nth-child(4)").addClass('selected');
    }    else if (value < blocksix) {
        removeSelected();
        $("#menu li:nth-child(5)").addClass('selected');
    } else {
        removeSelected();
        $("#menu li:last-child").addClass('selected'); 
    }
});
```

What am I missing? I have a working jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zer0ruth/pgbef/1/

Comment: Don't forget to put all that code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. If you fail to do it, the event listener (`.scroll`) will be never initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem is that you bind the scroll even on `#frame` while it should be on `window`.

But well, I saw that only after playing around with you code, so I have a free optimised code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pgbef/15/.

Saving you position in array is better than having 6 var and you can had a section without changing code:

```
var position = [];

$('.block').each(function(){
    position.push(Math.abs($(this).position().top))
})
```

Then your scroll function is way shorter too!

```
$(window).scroll( function() {

    var value = $(this).scrollTop() + $('#menu').height();

    $.each(position, function(i){
        if(this > value){
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $("#menu li").eq(i-1).addClass('selected');
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant, Thanks Karl-André